# Why does this compile? Java

Tags: java, collections, compilation, wildcard

I was taught that the following compiles:

```
Collection <? extends T> collection;
List<T> list;
collection = list; // Compiles
```

With the reason that "that's how Java developers defined it". I would like to know the rationale behind it. It compiles but can make problems during runtime (e.g. we wouldn't be able to add any objects to `collection`).

Any clarification would be appreciated.

Edit: I am referring to the fact that an `Object` of generic type `? extends T` is pointing to an `Object` of generic type `T`. It seems rather counterintuitive.

Comment: "know the rationale behind it" - so you must ask  the developers - we can only guess at best || and WHY should it not compile {assuming `T` is a class/type, and `list`  is initialized}?

Comment: Adding to a collection of a wildcard parameterized type (that is, the element type is something with a wildcard `?`) is not possible anyway, so you won't get a problem at runtime.

Comment: still not sure what you question is about... `List` is a subtype of `Collection`, `? extends T>` contains `T`, so `List<T>` is a subtype of `Collection<? extends T>` and Widening Reference Conversion can be applied. (BTW it is not a runtime problem, but a compile time problem - the compiler should  complain if trying to add to `collection`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Edit: I am referring to the fact that an `Object` of generic type `? extends T` is pointing to an `Object` of generic type `T`. It seems rather counterintuitive.

To understand this, you have to understand what exactly a `Collection<? extends T>` is.

It is: a `Collection` with elements of **a specific, but unknown type** (indicated by the `?`) that extends `T`.

Note that it is **not** a `Collection` of objects of arbitrary (and possibly different) types that extend `T` (this is a misconception that many developers have about generic wildcards).

It's perfectly OK that you can assign a `List<T>` to a variable of type `Collection<? extends T>`, because `List` is a subtype of `Collection`, and the elements of a `List<T>` are indeed of the type `? extends T`. (In this particular case, the actual type is the type `T` itself, but that still matches "some unknown type `?` that extends `T`").

Note that using the wildcard actually throws away information about the exact type of the elements of the collection - it makes Java forget the exact type, and only makes it remember that it's an unknown type that extends `T`.

You cannot add anything to a collection of a wildcard parameterized type such as a `Collection<? extends T>`, precisely because the information about the exact type of the elements is missing. If you would try to add an element to such a collection, there's no way for the compiler to check if the type of the element you're adding is the right type.

If you try to call `add()` on a `Collection<? extends T>` you will get a compile error that says that the type of the object you're adding is not of the type "capture of ... of `? extends T`". That basically means: "I cannot check that the object you're trying to add is of the unknown type `? extends T`".

The type can also not be checked at runtime because of type erasure: type arguments are a compile-time only thing in Java, at runtime they don't exist anymore so also then there's not enough information to check that the element you're adding is of the right type.

Answer (score 2):

It is because `Collection` is an interface. `List` is also an interface which `extends` Collection interface.

By `Object oriented principles`, parent class reference can hold the child class reference!

For e.g. If I have below

```
class Parent {
//Some code
}

class Child extends Parent {
//Some code
}
```

I can do this

```
Parent parentObject = new Child();
parentObject.childMethod();  or parentObject.parentMethod();
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html This docs can help !

Comment: I think that the answer should also mention [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html).

Comment: Thank you. Of course, but it was not what i meant. I might have not clarified myself - I am referring to the wildcard and to the generic type. It seems strange to me that a collection of something that extends T can point to a list of type T. If T = Number then a collection of Double can point to a list of Number - that's what's weird to me.